# Why can't I access my int array values that I made in my main method from another method? (beginner Java coder)

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

I am making a program that is simple for my school project, I am asking for a list then return either a max, min, or average. I make an array in the class then edit the values in my main method, I am trying to access the new values from my other methods but cant, IDK why.

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class numbersAreWeird {

```
    private static double[] thing;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        print("Hello");
        print("What is the length of your set of numbers?");
        int whyEven = in.nextInt();
        
        thing = new double[whyEven];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < thing.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("What do you want to place for " + i  + " ?");
            whyEven = in.nextInt();
            thing [i] = whyEven;
        }
             
        print("This is your arrray " + Arrays.toString(thing));
        
        print("Do you want to [1] Find the max [2] the min");
        print(" [3] find the average");
        int tree = in.nextInt();
        
        if(tree == 1)
        {
            getMax();
        }
        if(tree == 2)
        {
            getMin();
        }
        if(tree == 3)
        {
            getAve();
        }
            
    }
```

public static String getMax()
{

```
        Double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < thing.length; i++)
        {
            if(max<thing[i])
                max = thing[i];
        }
        
        return ("The Max value of the list is ")+ max;
    }
    
    public static String getMin()
    {
        Double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < thing.length; i++)
        {
            if(min>thing[i])
                min = thing[i];
        }
        
        return ("The Min value of the list is ") + min;
    }
    
    public static String getAve()
    {
        int total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < thing.length; i++)
        {
            total += thing[i];
            count++;
        }
        
        return ("The average of the list is ") + total/count;
    }
        
    public static void print(String str)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

}// end of class

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: Your code formatting needs to be fixed. And your tags need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you intended to print rather than return, or rather, forgot to print the returned value.

You should be printing the returned value (which involves less of a fix up with your code) like so:

```
if (tree == 1) {
    print(getMax());
}else if (tree == 2) {
    print(getMin());
}else if (tree == 3) {
    print(getAve());
}
```

Also, I replaced the 3 `if` statements with 1 `if` and 2 `else if` statements.